# Utilizar JSON em biblioteca JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, json

Estou utilizando a biblioteca "Vegas Background SlideShow" em um projeto com o seguinte código:

```
<script>
    $("#main").vegas({
        slides: [
        { src: "assets/site/img/uploads/banners/01.jpg" },
        { src: "assets/site/img/uploads/banners/02.jpg" },
        { src: "assets/site/img/uploads/banners/03.jpg" },
        { src: "assets/site/img/uploads/banners/04.jpg" }
        ],
        animation: 'random',
        align: 'center',
        valign: 'center',
        cover: 'false',
        delay: 9000,
        transitionDuration: 1000,
        timer: false,
        overlay: 'assets/site/vendors/vegas/overlays/07.png',
        walk: function(index) {
            if (index == 2) {
                $('#info').text("Slide index " + index);
            }
        }
    });

    $('a.slide-previous').on('click', function(e) {
        $("#main").vegas('previous');
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('a.slide-next').on('click', function(e) {
        $("#main").vegas('next');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

Assim como está ela funciona perfeitamente, mas as imagens a serem exibidas devem ser provenientes de uma consulta no banco de dados. Sendo assim, eu estou criando um JSON cujo resultado eu consigo imprimir assim:

```
var obj = JSON.parse('<?= $jsonImagens; ?>');
```

O resultado é o seguinte:

```
[["assets/site/img/uploads/banners/01.jpg","assets/site/img/uploads/banners/02.jpg","assets/site/img/uploads/banners/03.jpg","assets/site/img/uploads/banners/04.jpg"]]
```

Eu estou realizando a consulta no banco e colocando o resultado no array da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
$imagens = array();
$sql = "select * from tb_banner where status = 1";
$search_query = mysql_query($sql);
while($select = mysql_fetch_array($search_query)){
    $imagens[] = $select["imagem"];
    $textos[] = $select["texto_principal"];
}

$res = array($imagens);
$jsonImagens = json_encode($res, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
?>
```

A minha pergunta é: o que eu devo fazer para consumir este resultado no lugar da estrutura em que eu declaro as imagens de forma fixa? Ou seja, como eu declaro este JSON no lugar do código abaixo?

```
slides: [
        { src: "assets/site/img/uploads/banners/01.jpg" },
        { src: "assets/site/img/uploads/banners/02.jpg" },
        { src: "assets/site/img/uploads/banners/03.jpg" },
        { src: "assets/site/img/uploads/banners/04.jpg" }
        ],
```

Obrigado pela ajuda!!!

Comment: Algum motivo para seu JSON ser um  array de arrays de strings? E não apenas um array de string?

Comment: Veja só a edição que eu fiz. Aquela é a forma com que eu estou colocando os dados no Array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloca esse `var obj = JSON.parse('<?= $jsonImagens; ?>');` antes do código dos slides, e depois faz um mapeamento dessa array para formatar como precisas.

No exemplo em baixo transformo cada elemento da array num objeto com a chave `src` e o valor original desse elemento da array como chave.

O código poderia ficar assim:

```
<script>
    var obj = JSON.parse('<?= $jsonImagens; ?>');
    var slides = obj[0].map(function(img){
        return {src: img};
    });
    $("#main").vegas({
        slides: slides,
        animation: 'random',
        align: 'center',
        valign: 'center',
        cover: 'false',
        delay: 9000,
        transitionDuration: 1000,
        timer: false,
        overlay: 'assets/site/vendors/vegas/overlays/07.png',
        walk: function(index) {
            if (index == 2) {
                $('#info').text("Slide index " + index);
            }
        }
    });

    $('a.slide-previous').on('click', function(e) {
        $("#main").vegas('previous');
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('a.slide-next').on('click', function(e) {
        $("#main").vegas('next');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

#### Nota:

no PHP estás a enviar uma array com uma array dentro, isto é desnecessário e faz com que no JavaScript tenhas de usar `var slides = obj[0].map`. O ideal era ter no JavaScript `var slides = obj.map` e no PHP:

```
// $res = array($imagens); <- retirar esta linha e mudar em baixo
$jsonImagens = json_encode($imagens, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Funcionou perfeitamente aqui cara!!!

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer essa transformação você poderia utilizar a função map do javascript.

Ficaria assim

```
var listaUrls = obj[0].map(function( url ){
      return { src: url };
 })
```

Comment: Você pode me dizer onde é que vai este código? Peço perdão por esse tipo de dúvida, mas é que eu não tenho familiaridade com JavaScript.

Eu tentei chamar somente a variável listaUrls no lugar onde estou chamando as imagens fixas mas não obtive sucesso. Também tentei outras formas aqui mas confesso que não consegui =/